# Notice: Undefined offset preg_split

Tags: php

My page is throwing php notice, i can ignore them by hiding notices in config file php.ini, but am think of resolving it once & for all.

The code is

```
       <?php 
            $timeframe = preg_split('#(?<=\d)(?=[a-z])#i',$value->time_frame); 
            echo $timeframe[0]." ".ucfirst($timeframe[1]); 
        ?>
```

the undefined offset is coming on this line:

```
echo $timeframe[0]." ".ucfirst($timeframe[1]);
```

Comment: Whats is returning in `$value->time_frame`

Comment: You simply need to check whether $timeframe[0] and $timeframe[1] are set before using these indexes

Comment: Time frame echos 1 item from 4 variables (Daily, Weekly, Fortnightly or Monthly)